# How to Change Drop Down menu style on actionBar in android?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar

I am creating an android app in which i am using a drop down menu on action bar.
All i ned to change the view of this drop down something like whatsapp

For example:-
[image]

here on whatsapp attach button a table layout comes with item but in my case there is only a simple list without items .

[image]

**I Also want to change icon of menu darken by yellow.**

Somebody please help me how i can make a dropdown menu with table layout and images . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The ActionBar is not designed for such a use-case. The `ActionBar` buttons are meant to replace the old options menu that could be triggered with a separate hardware button on older devices (pre HC/ICS). The overflow button (the one with the 3 dots) that you've drawn in your sketch is used when there isn't enough room to show all buttons (the Android framework takes care of this automatically), so those will be grouped in the overflow menu. Overriding this behavior is a bad idea (if even possible).

Instead you should consider another approach: Add one `ActionButton` to the `ActionBar` that is meant to handle the color chooser. When this button is clicked the best solution is to show an AlertDialog (you can easily insert your on Views here that show the colors you want) because this will work best even if the button is hidden in the overflow menu.

Alternatively you could trigger a [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) or implement some [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) or [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go for [QuickAction3D](https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D) view which will full fill your requirement.